# read item in unread inbox method again

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

I'm getting a read item in the inbox/unread method, again. This happened before, but I can't find the post about it (I'm pretty sure you fixed/explained it). But the item is very old, not a cache thing, and it stays in the method, with the is_unread field set to false.

It only appears if there is another item, if there are no unread items then the API returns nothing as expected

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was a race between fetching the count of unread inbox items and actually populating the results.

A fix has been deployed.